# Implementation against two dependency API versions with Java & Maven

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hive, parquet

We have a Java Maven project with dependencies to a library (Parquet within Hive/Hadoop API to be specific). The API of the dependency (parquet.hadoop.api to org.apache.parquet.hadoop.api) changed in a certain Parquet/Hadoop version. But our project shall be able to compile against new AND old versions.

How can I write two implementations for dependencies in different versions and somewhow switch at build time? We don't want to maintain separate projects.

One idea was to use two maven profiles with modules:

- Two additional modules implementing the two variants of the same class.
- Two maven profiles for the old and the new version. Each profile includes a different module

But maybe there is a better or completely different approach? Can we just use profiles without adding modules (which we don't have yet in the project)?

Comment: from my own experience: use maven profiles. I don't know if this will be the best option, but it's what I have seen work ok in several different projects with this restrictions

Comment: @Repoker thanks. Maven profiles are fine, but the problem is that we don't have modules yet and we would not like to add them unless we really need them, because they add some complexity/overhead. I was hoping that there is another solution without modules.

Comment: @Repoker addition: I guess you mean maven profiles combined with modules? Because I am not aware of any way to include/exclude source files via a Maven profile.

Comment: Make two different projects one for the new API and one for the old API put the appropriate code to the appropriate project. This means each project can have separate dependencies and can run it's own tests against it. Profiles are a bad idea for such things..If you need to have both things how would handle to build for both areas with profiles? That would become a mess...

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks, but not sure if I get you. Having two projects means duplicating of 99.9% percent of code (in our case), because only one little class is depending on the dependency and has to exist in two versions. I would handle build by just specifying a profile, e.g. -P new-version or old-version, and based on this the specific module is included, either with the new, or with the old version of the class. But ideally I would also like to avoid introducing modules, to keep it simple.

Comment: Hi @andre.hacker, did you find any solution to this?